# The way how to fix the error in Solr system

Tags: apache, solr

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: 
QueryElevationComponent missing config file: 'elevate.xml either: 
F:\dev\solr-7.4.0\server\solr\new_core\conf\elevate.xml or F:\dev\solr-7.4.0\server\solr\new_core\data\elevate.xml 
must exist, but not both.
```

Creating the core in Solr, I got this error 
Why was it happened?

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the `elevate.xml` file. You either remove the reference to the file from your configuration (where you have [configured the Query Elevation Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-query-elevation-component.html), or you add an empty file.